# Summary over sets of points

Tags: postgresql, window-functions

Using postgresql 10

I have a table gpspoints which among other things contains

```
id    dist
 1    NULL
 2     2.3
 3     4.4
 4     1.7
 5     1.2
 6     2.7
```

and so on

Dist is distance in meter since the previous point
In addition, I have a table trip that gives the first and last id from the gpstable for a trip. Each point may belong to several overlapping trip.

The trip table is then like:

```
 id start  end
  1   1     4
  2   2     3
  3   3     5
```

When I do my query I know that start < end and there will never be more than one defined trip for each gpspoint

I would like to add up the length of the trip for each point that is defined as a start point, i.e.

```
start  length
 1       9.4   # (2.3 + 4.4 + 1.7)
 2       6.1   # (4.4 + 1.7)
 3       7.3   # (4.4 + 1.7 + 1.2)
```

Writing this, I realize that a possible solution would be to make a new table containing the trip id and the gpspointid for each trip. But as the gpspoint table has a few millions rows and there may be up to a few hundred trips that each point is a member of (Each of the trips may contain a few hundred points) and the trips are clearly defined by their start and end point, my question is still

Is there a way to sum a number between two given id with varying distance between the ids? (if there always had been the same number of points in a trip, I could have made the sums using windowing functions)

Comment: Can you explain the `2       6.1   # (4.4 + 1.7)` result?

Comment: I don't understand `9.4 # (2.3 + 4.4 + 1.7)` where does 9.4 come from? 2.3 + 4.4 + 1.7 = 8.4

Comment: Can you dump actual data and your desired output? Such as the GPS points.

Comment: 2/3 of the addition problems are wrong. =(

Comment: Could you please post your table structures as DDL (`CREATE TABLE blah  (...);`) and data as DDL (`INSERT INTO blah VALUES (...);`), **or** provide an SQLFiddle or similar!

Answer (score 2):

I am not entirely sure I understood you, but maybe something like this:

```
select t.id, 
       sum(p.dist) as trip_distance, 
       array_agg(p.dist) as dist_values,
       array_agg(p.id) as points
from gpspoints p
  join trip t on p.id between t.start_point and t.end_point
group by t.id;
```

For the following sample data:

```
create table gpspoints  (id int primary key, dist numeric);
create table trip (id integer primary key, start_point int, end_point int);

insert into gpspoints 
values
  (1, NULL),
  (2,  2.3),
  (3,  4.4),
  (4,  1.7),
  (5,  1.2),
  (6,  2.7);

insert into trip
values
  (1, 1, 4),
  (2, 2, 3),
  (3, 3, 5);
```

The query returns:

```
id | trip_distance | dist_values        | points   
---+---------------+--------------------+----------
 1 |           8.4 | {NULL,2.3,4.4,1.7} | {1,2,3,4}
 2 |           6.7 | {2.3,4.4}          | {2,3}    
 3 |           7.3 | {4.4,1.7,1.2}      | {3,4,5}
```

The columns `dist_values` and `points` are just there for debugging purposes to validate that the correct points were included.

Comment: +1 for the non-GIS solution. If he can't use GIS this is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

## GIS Solution

This is a GIS problem at the core. Use PostGIS.

```
CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
```

Select the points and use the aggregate [`ST_MakeLine(.. ORDER BY)`](http://www.postgis.net/docs/ST_MakeLine.html) They're ordered. It'll look like this. [`ST_Length`](http://postgis.org/docs/ST_Length.html) will return the length in meters.

```
SELECT ST_Length(ST_MakeLine(geog ORDER BY id)) AS length_in_meters
FROM foo
CROSS JOIN LATERAL ST_MakePoint(long,lat)::geog AS geog
WHERE ID between start AND end;
```

This assumes somewhere you have the points collected in time table.

```
id | long | lat
0  | ...  | ...
```

Hint, if that assumption is right, you should be storing these as `geog` and not `long` and `lat`.

```
BEGIN;
  ALTER TABLE foo
    ADD COLUMN geog geography;
  ALTER TABLE foo
    SET geog = ST_MakePoint(long,lat);
  ALTER TABLE foo
    DROP COLUMN long,
    DROP COLUMN lat;
COMMIT;
```

I used a `CROSS JOIN LATERAL` to isolate the complexity. If the types were GIS types you wouldn't need that. So having run the above, you just delete that line.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to first calculate the distances from point 1 using a window function and then join twice to the `trip` table:

```
with g as 
  ( select id, 
           coalesce(dist, 0)  as dist, 
           coalesce(sum(dist) over (order by id), 0)  as sd 
    from gpspoints
  ) 
select t.start_point, 
       t.end_point, 
       g2.sd - g1.sd + g1.dist  as length
from trip as t 
  join g as g1 on t.start_point = g1.id
  join g as g2 on t.end_point = g2.id 
order by t.id ;
```